# Retrieving table that has a one to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, one-to-many

I have two tables:

```
Detection{
    DetectionId int
    ....
    ...
    ...
}

DetectionInfo{
    DetectionId int
    Name char
    val char
}
```

There is a one to many relationship between these two tables.

I want to retrieve the detections that have BOTH  val = "DOWN" and val = "Blue"

Here is my solution:

```
SELECT * FROM Detection a WHERE a.DetectionId IN 
    (SELECT c.DetectionId FROM DetectionInfo c where c.val = "DOWN" and c.Detection IN
          (SELECT d.DetectionId FROM DetectionInfo d 
              WHERE d.val = "Blue"))
```

Is there a better (efficient) way to do this?

Comment: You could join to the DetectionInfo table twice - once for DOWN and once for Blue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method to get the ids:

```
select detectionid
from detectioninfo
where val in ('DOWN', 'BLUE')
group by detectionid
having count(distinct val) = 2;
```

You can use `join`, `in`, or `exists` to get the rest of the information from the `detection` table if you need it.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer! I was wondering why cant I add "and" after val in (('DOWN', 'BLUE')) and check other columns like name.

Comment: @HamidY. . . . Because `val` cannot take on two different values in the same row.